# How to add roles from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have my ASP.NET MVC 4 project and database (SQL Server 2008)

And I've created an entity framework model, with auto-generated models.

And in the database there is a table called Roles (2 fields, Id and name)

There are 3 roles: admin, moderator, user.

Plus Account controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    private korovin_idzEntities db = new korovin_idzEntities();

    //
    // GET: /Account/LogOn

    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOn

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model/*, string returnUrl*/)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.username == model.UserName && x.password == model.Password).FirstOrDefault();

            if (user != null)
            {
                user.isRemember = model.RememberMe;
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.UserName = model.UserName;
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.UserName, false); 
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Where and how can i initialize roles in my asp.net mvc application? I've tried to check whether role exists and to initialize role by rolemanager in account controller, but i think it's not a good solution.

Is it possible to initialize roles in global.asax.cs?

I know that I should attach roles to user in log on function.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, I thought that there is some kind of a structure for storing a names of roles and there is needed to initialize this structure, but i was wrong, and after googling, I've found the solution:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string[] roles = LookupRolesForUser(context.User.Identity.Name);
            var newUser = new GenericPrincipal(context.User.Identity, roles);
            context.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = newUser;
        }
    }

    #region helper

    private string[] LookupRolesForUser(string userName)
    {
        string[] roles = new string[1];
        CosmosMusic.Models.korovin_idzEntities db = new CosmosMusic.Models.korovin_idzEntities();
        var roleId = db.Users.Where(x => x.username == userName).FirstOrDefault().id_role;
        roles[0] = db.Role.Where(y => y.id_role == roleId).FirstOrDefault().name;

        return roles;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: That's one way to do it: another would be to create a custom RoleProvider.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx